Can I route washer hoses in a conduit behind the wall?
I'm installing a washer in a nook under a staircase landing, and I'd like to conceal the washer hoses but keep both the supply shutoffs and the standpipe accessible and visible (the standpipe is not allowed to go in a cupboard or closet if I'm reading the plumbing code correctly).
My plan is to have a ~2" conduit with an opening behind the washer that goes into the wall (I happen to have enough wall thickness to make this easy) and that emerges inside a standard washer outlet box (probably at one side of it).
Then I just fish the hoses through the conduit as I slide the washer back into its nook. The visible part of the hoses ends up entirely within the outlet box.
I can't be the first person to think of this, but with a decent amount of googling I can't find an example of someone doing it, so I feel like I must be missing something.
Is this something that's commonly done? What could possibly go wrong (that couldn't go wrong with standard exposed washer hoses)?
In some ways it's a bit like how some people route their HDMI and power cables from a wall-mounted TV to whatever cabinet their media player/game console/etc. is in. Or like one of these power outlets with the little brush plate: https://www.amazon.com/Concealer-Connection-Management-HT2102WHV1-Hardwired/dp/B003JUBMCI

You may need a sketch, because I'm having difficulty understanding your objective here—so others may too.  What's wrong with the traditional "hoses go from washer to outlet box and get hidden behind the washer when you push it back" method?
